# Align text from bottom of div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I need to align some text in a div with some spacing to the bottom of the div. How can I set the space (for example 10 or 20px) between the bottom of my div and my text ?

Here is the sample code:

```css
.modultext {
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
 padding-top: auto;
 padding-bottom: 17px; <!-- Space from the bottom -->
}
```

```html
<div class="modultext">Sample text</div>
```

Comment: yo can use `position: absolute` and `bottom: 15px`

Comment: .modultext{float: left}

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CHCVF/3/

Comment: add this below padding bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `table-cell` layout together with `vertical-align` property:

```css
.modultext{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
  padding-bottom: 17px; <!-- Space from the bottom -->
}
```

```html
<div class="modultext">Sample text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1th: Use `line-height`**

```
line-height: 5cm;
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/q357xam7/)

---

**2th: Use `absolute`**

```
.modultext span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q357xam7/1/)**

---

**3th: Use `Padding`**

```
.modultext span {
    padding-top: 70px;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q357xam7/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `line-height` as twice the height of the div. This will always set the text to bottom of the div.

```css
.modultext {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
  padding-top: auto;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  <!-- Space from the bottom -->
}
```

```html
<div class="modultext">Sample text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a span to cover the text.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/ppw74d02/1/)

This is what i comment [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/ppw74d02/2/)

**Style:**

```
.modultext{
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
span{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modultext"><span>Sample text</span></div>
```